# How to install GENViewer Lite 1.15 on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I do a lot of genealogical research, and have downloaded and saved (in the download arrow at the top right of the Ubuntu window) a GEDcom file reader, but I can't get it to install on Ubuntu 16.04.

All I get is a folder full of other folders that do nothing.

Software/Link: http://www.mudcreeksoftware.com/genviewer_lite.htm

How to install GENViewer on Ubuntu?

Comment: http://www.mudcreeksoftware.com/genviewer_lite.htm

Comment: The program you are trying to install is for Windows, so you'll need to run it either in a virtual machine (Windows running inside Ubuntu) or with Wine.

Comment: I have no idea how to do either of those things. :(

Comment: You can try this alternative `gramps` https://gramps-project.org/ to install it, open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install gramps`

Comment: @LexiAngel In that case, try the program Mark suggested first, it supports GEDcom file format. If it doesn't do what you need, I can try GENViewer Lite on my system later today and give you a step-by-step if nobody has done so by then.

Comment: @bgse, thank you. I found and downloaded Wine too. :)

Comment: This is not working the way I need it to. Gramps reads the GEDcom file, and opens it into a huge tree. I don't want to import the GEDcom I just want to read separate database profiles. The GENViewer opens the GEDcom into a database, where you can use a slider to go from one person profile to the next

Comment: @bgse No problem. I managed to install it using Wine. :) Thank you.

Comment: @LexiAngel Looks like I posted my solution at the same time :(

Comment: It took a while to figure out, but I got there in the end. @andrew.46 Thank you so much, this would have been very handy had I had any problems installing with Wine... this will hopefully help others though. :)

Answer (score 1):

The application seems to run well enough under Wine. I got it all running with the following three commands:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
wget http://www.mudcreeksoftware.com/GENViewerLite.exe
wine GENViewerLite.exe
```

I have not tested it *extensively* but below is a screenshot of it running on my Xenial installation:

[image]

Hopefully it will work well on your system too...